# Unable to Create a Juniper VPN connection

Tags: release-juno, vpn

I've recently installed Juno and I simply love the clean design. Kudos. The issue I'm having is trying to connect to my work VPN. I installed **openconnect** and **NetworkManager-openconnect**, but the only option I see when adding a new VPN connection is OpenVPN. I'm specifically looking for Juniper or Cisco compatible connections.

I was able to connect via terminal. In all honesty I'm not sure if it worked. Is that the same thing as having a connection through the GUI. It's a silly question, but doing VPN outside of a GUI is new to me.

> openconnect --juniper URL -u USERNAME

I'm new to Pantheon desktop and all my search results aren't helping. I figured since the desktop was based on GNOME that the process would be the same on my Fedora box, but it's different. What am I missing here? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Juno (which is based on Ubuntu 18.04) you should be able to follow this guide: https://grepitout.com/install-openconnect-ubuntu-vpn-client/

The GUI in elementary will look a bit different, but the funtionality is the same. I tried it myself on a VirtualBox Juno installation and it worked like a charm :)

Comment: Thank you, this worked. Apparently what I missed was `network-manager-openconnect-gnome`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to choose the PPTP protocol

[image: PPTP protocol]

Then just enter your login credentials on the new window:

[image: login credentials]

Comment: Thank you for the screenshots. It didn't fix my issue specifically, but it helped me see that I was limiting myself to what I thought was the solution.